# switch on types if cases are disjoint

Tags: c#, performance, types, switch-statement

According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/, the `switch` statement used on types is order-sensitive:

> The order of case clauses now matters: Just like catch clauses, the
>   case clauses are no longer necessarily disjoint, and the first one
>   that matches gets picked.

If the `switch` statement used on types respects order, I assume it is nothing more than an `if-else-if` chain under the hood. This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch hints to that as well: First it gives an example of a `switch` statement on types, then it says "Without pattern matching, this code might be written as follows" and shows an `if-else-if` chain.

But in my scenario, the types are unrelated in terms of inheritance or interface implementation, so the cases are definitely disjoint.

1. Will the compiler find this out and turn the `switch` statement into a lookup table automatically?
2. If not, is there a way to force the compiler to turn it into a lookup table?

---

Scenario:

I am parsing data from an auto-generated object structure, that was created by xsd.exe from an xsd xml schema, into my own data structure. Because the xsd schema makes use of a lot of choice statements, I often end up using this pattern:

```
static IContent ParseContent(object c)
{
    // Because of the choice statements in the xsd, the object c can be an instance
    // of many different (auto-generated) classes which are not related to each other
    // in terms of inheritance or interface implementation.

    if (c is class1 c1) // class1 is an auto-generated class from the xsd schema
        return ParseClass1(c1);
    else if (c is class2 c2) // class2 is an auto-generated class from the xsd schema
        return ParseClass2(c2);
    ....
    else if (c is class20 c20) // class20 is an auto-generated class from the xsd schema
        return ParseClass20(c20);
    else
        throw new ArgumentException(...);
}

static MyClass1 ParseClass1(class1 c1) { ... } // MyClass1 implements IContent
...
static MyClass20 ParseClass20(class20 c20) { ... } // MyClass20 implements IContent
```

I recently decided to optimize for performance, that's why I'm interested in the mechanics of `switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Will the compiler find this out and turn the switch statement into a lookup table automatically?

No, because it cannot guarantee that the classes would remain disjoint after your code has been compiled into a DLL.

> 2. If not, is there a way to force the compiler to turn it into a lookup table?

If your always switch on a leaf type, you could turn this into a switch on a full name of the type:

```
switch (c?.GetType().FullName) {
    case "MyNamespace.Class1": {
        return ParseClass1((MyNamespace.Class1)c);
    }
    case "MyNamespace.Class2": {
        return ParseClass2((MyNamespace.Class2)c);
    }
    ...
}
```

You could eliminate the switch altogether, replacing it with dynamic dispatch:

```
static IContent ParseContent(dynamic c) => ParseClass(c);
//                           ^^^^^^^
// This is the part where "magic" takes place

IContent ParseClass(class1 c) {...}
IContent ParseClass(class2 c) {...}
...
IContent ParseClass(class20 c) {...}
IContent ParseClass(object c) => throw new ArgumentException(...);
```

Comment: Regarding your `FullName` suggestion: is there a way to make this work even with an obfuscator? `nameof(class1)` will not give the full name...

Comment: @Kjara You should be able to use `typeof(class1).FullName`.

Comment: According to https://tudorturcu.wordpress.com/2015/07/18/nameof-and-obfuscators/, `nameof` is applied at compile time (before obfuscation). I assume `typeof` is as well, which means that `typeof(...).FullName` gives the name before obfuscation. But `GetType().FullName` gives the runtime type name, i.e. after obfuscation. So it seems the approach will not work...

Comment: @Kjara `typeof` is applied at compile time, but `FullName` is not. It will provide an obfuscated name.

Comment: Hm, but then, wouldn't the runtime application give a performance penalty? I wonder how significant this is. Seems I need to try it out. But this runtime-dependency is kinda unsatisfactory.